# If @media all is declared in css then max-device-width is necessary?

Tags: css, media-queries

I am using media query `@media all and (max-width:500px) {..}` to make site design responsive. It is working fine on my opera mini. But i have not tested it on other other mobile browsers. Will it also work on other mobile browsers or i have to add **(max-device-width:500px)** in this media query.

Answer (score 0):

`max-width` is fine enough

```
/* smaller than 980 */
@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
    your css here
}

/* smaller than 650 */
@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
    your css here
}

/* smaller than 480 */
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    your css here
}
```